# Установка SSL сертификата: как поставить на бесплатный хостинг, если нет ни консоли, ни панели управления хостингом?

Tags: ssl, https, хостинг, openssl, сертификат

Хочу поставить Lets Encrypt на на бесплатный хостинг, но нигде, в том числе на сайте самого Lets Encrypt не нашел, как это осуществить, если нет ни консоли, ни панели управления, вроде ISP. Гуру, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Если нет доступа к консоле (sudo), то подозреваю что никак) Вообще бесплатный хостинг такое себе, учитывая что полно довольно хороших хостингов за копейки) Кроме ssl там еще может всплыть масса подводных камней, подумайте об этом)

Comment: А как туда ваши файлы попадают и сервер настраивается?

Comment: @AlexeyTen есть панель управления, я установил file zilla и загружаю изменения через него

Comment: @AlexeyTen но любые доп функции он оставляет в платной версии. планировщика задач нет, консоли - так же

Comment: Ставится специальная приблуда - сервер сертификатов (надо погуглить есть где-то иструкции). 1. Поставить "сервер". 2. Потом сам на себя отправляется запрос на сертификат в менеджере сертификатов. 3. На "сервеве" подтвержаем запрос. 4. В ответ получаем "бесплатный" сертификат. Минус - сертификат не доверенный. Потом сертификат подкидывается в IIS/апатч/и.т.д.и.т.п. тоже  можно найти как подвязать. Если там на сервере вообще поднят https.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю бесплатный хостинг не дает возможности на SSL можете использовать Cloudflare

Comment: Если на хостинге нет SSL, то получается, что канал связи между Cloudflare и хостингом всё равно будет не защищён и потенциально уязвим для mitm-атак (хотя вероятность такой атаки очень маленькая, но всё-таки не нулевая)

Comment: @andreymal, ну у меня там нечего будет взламывать. Мне ssl нужен только для того, чтобы telegram бот отправлял веб-хук серверу.. без https не соглашается... А так весь проект учебный маленький и только интереса ради

Comment: Да если нужен только https используйте cloudflare, если что помогу